# How to make more than one page in WP8 development ( read additional details)?

Tags: windows-phone-8

when i make an app for windows phone using VS2012 express for windows phone, im stuck with one page or one main page. I mean i want my app to run, then when i press a button i want to move to another page (with it own text, buttons, app bar buttons), and, for example, when i press an app bar button i want to move to another page ( (with it own text, buttons, app bar buttons) 
the image is from multiple apps, anyone know how to combine them into a single app? 
Thanx

https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/51b770ed4346493e89d56b1b8bea1bda_A.png?a=answers&mr=0&x=1388830570&s=985ca7faf1bcb12dde3e129de1953c9e

Answer (score 0):

Please read the basic tutorials first.

For example, [this one on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) explains how to do page navigation.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + textBox1.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```